# lockfile_parser.r :48:in `parse_source': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been messing around with both RubyOnRails3 and Git for the first time. Everything had been going along smoothly until all of a sudden any rails related command line argument stopped working. Unfortunately I have no idea what caused this or how to go about fixing it.

Here's the output from the command line

```
C:\railstest\railsproject>rails
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb
:48:in `parse_source': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/lockf
ile_parser.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/lockf
ile_parser.rb:14:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/lockf
ile_parser.rb:14:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/defin
ition.rb:43:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/defin
ition.rb:43:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/dsl.r
b:122:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/dsl.r
b:122:in `to_definition'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/defin
ition.rb:20:in `build'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler.rb:12
8:in `definition'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler.rb:11
6:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler.rb:10
0:in `setup'
        from C:/railstest/railsproject/config/boot.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

I'm not exactly sure what other information to provide

Comment: Thanks for that solution, it was exactly the problem I had. Note : that you might have to delete the gemfile.lock file for every branch in which the problem occurs Least, I had to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems like there is some problem in the `Gemfile.lock` file. You can try deleting this file and run `bundle install` again to see if it can recreate it correctly.

Comment: Also, perhaps do a `git diff Gemfile.lock` or something similar to see if you accidentally modified the file, like I did. This was you don't have to trash it.

Comment: @DerekB. good point. It's not a good idea to delete the lock file outright, since it specifies the versions your app currently depends on and is tested with.